# Dimensional Question

Tags: spacetime, physical-constants

When I was studying about the fact that no object can be smaller in length than Planck length. So should this imply that every object around us or possibly in the universe is three dimensional, i.e. has a thickness. As all the three dimensions in any object couldn't be less than Planck length?

Comment: I don't understand your question. How does the first sentence imply the second?

Comment: It's more accurate to say that our theories of physics currently cannot describe objects smaller in length than Planck length.

Comment: Are you saying, if it were not for the Planck Length, there *would* exist objects in this universe which have no 3rd dimension?

Comment: As we know that our physics cannot described object smaller than planck length if we modify it we can consider that nothing is smaller than planck length. So if the nothing is smaller than planck length then the magnitude of dimensions shouldn't be less than planck length. If the magnitude of dimensions is not less than planck length then this should imply that every object in universe is three dimensional or more.  Is this?

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is necessary to reformulate the idea. In quantum world te particle is a wave of probability. You can compare it to an electromagnetic wave. In this case there is no thickness properly speaking. You can talk about a post probable place to find your particle, and not a thickness like of a matter.